# Работа с консолью(терминалом) Python

Tags: python

Кратко говоря, к этому коду:

```
import pyttsx3
text = 'Это работает'
tts = pyttsx3.init()
tts.setProperty('rate', 120)

volume = tts.getProperty('volume')
tts.setProperty('volume', volume+0.9)

# Задать голос по умолчанию
tts.setProperty('voice', 'ru')

tts.say(text)
tts.runAndWait()
```

Я хочу добавить что-то подобное:

```
if переменная == 'сообщение из консоли/терминала PyCharm':
   tts.say(text)
```

Можете подсказать библиотеку или другое решение? Библиотека argparse мне не помогла, а другие варианты я не нашёл... Извиняюсь за предположительно глупый вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = 'Это работает'
tts = pyttsx3.init()
tts.setProperty('rate', 120)

volume = tts.getProperty('volume')
tts.setProperty('volume', volume+0.9)

# Задать голос по умолчанию
tts.setProperty('voice', 'ru')
#ввод из терминала
text=str(input('Что мне сказать? '))
tts.say(text)
tts.runAndWait()
```

аналог аргпарсе

```
import docopt
_doc_="""I say.

Usage:
    file.py -t <text>
    file.py -text <text>

Options:
  -t --text Text for speach    

Description:
    The description of apps
"""
dc=docopt.docopt(_doc_, version='i say 1.0')
#file.py -t "the sample"
#{'--text': "the sample"}

tts.say(dc['text'],dc['t'])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)